# iOS storyBoard localization is not working without restart of the application

Tags: ios, swift, localization, storyboard

I want to change the language of the application. I have created two files for Main.strings in English and Hindi. Also Localizable.strings for both Hindi and English. Here is how I change the language :

```
 LocalizationSystem.sharedInstance.setLanguage(languageCode: "hi")

 UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight

 let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

 let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SwipeViewController")as! SwipeViewController

let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
 UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = navigationController
```

Here is the LocalizationSystem class

```
class LocalizationSystem : NSObject {

var bundle: Bundle!

class var sharedInstance: LocalizationSystem {
    struct Singleton {
        static let instance: LocalizationSystem = LocalizationSystem()
    }
    return Singleton.instance
}

override init() {
    super.init()
    bundle = Bundle.main
}

func localizedStringForKey(key:String, comment:String) -> String {
    return bundle.localizedString(forKey: key, value: comment, table: nil)
}

func localizedImagePathForImg(imagename:String, type:String) -> String {
    guard let imagePath =  bundle.path(forResource: imagename, ofType: type) else {
        return ""
    }
    return imagePath
}


func setLanguage(languageCode:String) {
    var appleLanguages = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "AppleLanguages") as! [String]
    appleLanguages.remove(at: 0)
    appleLanguages.insert(languageCode, at: 0)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(appleLanguages, forKey: "AppleLanguages")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize() //needs restrat

    if let languageDirectoryPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: languageCode, ofType: "lproj")  {
        bundle = Bundle.init(path: languageDirectoryPath)
    } else {
        resetLocalization()
    }
}

func resetLocalization() {
    bundle = Bundle.main
}

func getLanguage() -> String {
    let appleLanguages = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "AppleLanguages") as! [String]
    let preferredLanguage = appleLanguages[0]
    if preferredLanguage.contains("-") {
        let array = preferredLanguage.components(separatedBy: "-")
        return array[0]
    }
    return preferredLanguage
}

}
```

`Localizable.strings` file is changing but `Main.Strings` file doesn't changes without restart of the application.

I don't know what I am missing here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are probably missing the fact that it is a bit "harder" to change the localization without restart: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51153785/how-to-change-localization-language-without-restart-application-swift4

Comment: Thanks DominikBucher, Does it mean that I need to create an outlet of all the static text as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try this may Helps you:

```
if  LocalizationSystem.sharedInstance.getLanguage() == "en" {

Bundle.main.path(forResource: "en", ofType: "lproj")

} else if LocalizationSystem.sharedInstance.getLanguage() == "hi" {
Bundle.main.path(forResource: "hi", ofType: "lproj")

}
```

and you can add many more languages to your app and switch between them without restarting the app.