# IOS Key board language based on UIView displayed dynamically

Tags: ios, localization, uikeyboard

I am developing an app, where I display multiple UIViewController, each of them containing a UITextView for user to enter information based on their language preference. i am trying to figure out if the keyboard language preference can be dynamically changed based on the current UIView.

For instance, I will pass the language when the UIViewController is loaded, and the keyboard should automatically pick up the corresponding language and display for user interaction.

Not sure if this is achievable though.

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard can be changed by changing the device language settings (I believe). If you can switch the set language and then reload the input view then the keyboard should be updated.

To change the language, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29874319/1857279) is an accepted answer.

From there, `[myTextView reloadInputView]` should work to update the keyboard.